# Calling pcsclite using mono on 64-bit Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I have a .Net console application that uses winscard/pcsclite to communicate with a smart card.
It works without problems on Windows and 32-bit Linux but fails on 64-bit Linux.
The SCardTransmit function returns 0 but the RecvLength is not updated and no data is received.

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be in the call to the SCardTransmit function.
The Dllimport is specified like this.
I have also tried to specify the recvLen as IntPtr with the same result.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SCardIoRequest
{
    internal SCardIoRequest(CardProtocol protocol)
    {
        Protocol = (uint)protocol;
        Length = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCardIoRequest));
    }

    public uint Protocol;
    public uint Length;
}

[DllImport("Winscard.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SCardTransmit(IntPtr card, [In] ref SCardIoRequest sendPci, byte[] sendBuffer, uint sendLen, IntPtr recvPci, [Out] byte[] recvBuffer, ref int recvLen);
```

Additional information and logs:

```
mono version 2.10.8
pcsc-lite version 1.4.4

[centos@localhost ~]$ mono pcsctest.exe
Test PC/CS
SCardEstablishContext - returned 0
SCardListReaders - returned 0
SCardListReaders - returned 0
After GetReaders
Reader: OmniKey CardMan 6121 00 00
SCardConnect - returned 0
Connect to Card, protocol: 2
SCardTransmit - returned 0
recvlen = 256
  Serial: 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
SCardTransmit - returned 0

winscard_msg_srv.c:217:SHMProcessEventsServer() Common channel packet arrival
winscard_msg_srv.c:226:SHMProcessEventsServer() SHMProcessCommonChannelRequest detects: 7
pcscdaemon.c:174:SVCServiceRunLoop() A new context thread creation is requested: 7
winscard_svc.c:131:ContextThread() Thread is started: 7
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard_svc.c:179:ContextThread() Client is protocol version 2:2
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard.c:242:SCardEstablishContext() Establishing Context: 16985718
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard.c:298:SCardConnect() Attempting Connect to OmniKey CardMan 6121 00 00 using protocol: 2
prothandler.c:130:PHSetProtocol() Attempting PTS to T=1
ifdhandler.c:488:IFDHSetProtocolParameters() lun: 0, protocol T=1
winscard.c:433:SCardConnect() Active Protocol: T=1
winscard.c:443:SCardConnect() hCard Identity: eaf1
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard_svc.c:730:MSGCheckHandleAssociation() Client failed to authenticate
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard_svc.c:730:MSGCheckHandleAssociation() Client failed to authenticate
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard_svc.c:730:MSGCheckHandleAssociation() Client failed to authenticate
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard_svc.c:730:MSGCheckHandleAssociation() Client failed to authenticate
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard_svc.c:730:MSGCheckHandleAssociation() Client failed to authenticate
winscard_msg_srv.c:288:SHMProcessEventsContext() correctly processed client: 7
winscard.c:253:SCardReleaseContext() Releasing Context: 16985718
winscard.c:848:SCardDisconnect() Active Contexts: 1
winscard_msg_srv.c:276:SHMProcessEventsContext() Client has disappeared: 7
winscard_svc.c:144:ContextThread() Client die: 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not post your code so this is just a guess but it looks like the problem is in your interop code that specifies how data is marshaled between managed - C# - and unmanaged - C - memory. You are most likely facing the [famous C 'long' type marshaling problem](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Longs) I have also encountered during the development of multiplatform Pkcs11Interop project.

PCSC API uses the C 'long' type which is very difficult to marshal since there is no type in .NET that matches its size on all platforms. The problem is that the C 'long' type can be 4 bytes long on some platforms (Win32, Win64 and Unix32) and in the same time it can be 8 bytes long on the other platforms (Unix64). In .NET there is 'int' type which is 4 bytes long regardless of platform and there is 'long' type which is 8 bytes long regardless of platform. Neither of them can be used as a multiplatform alternative for C 'long' type and the only solution is to use and to marshal two different sets of functions and structures, one with 'int' .NET type for platforms where C 'long' type is 4 bytes long and the other with 'long' .NET type for platforms where C 'long' type is 8 bytes long.

To sum it up: You should fix your marshaling code or you should use better managed PCSC interop library that supports also platforms where C 'long' type is 8 bytes long. It looks like [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) could be a way but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: OK, thx for your input! I updated my question with the calling code.

Comment: @DanielPersson It is definitely not enough to change just the type of recvLen parameter. **You need to change the type of all affected parts of your interop code**. When speaking specifically about your SCardTransmit method then there is at least the sendLen parameter that needs to be changed. And the same goes for SCardIoRequest members.